# vimscript match combine \V with word boundaries

Tags: regex, vim, match, word-boundary

I have the problem that I want to combine the \V and word boundaries in the match function, like this:

```
let index = match(line, "\\<\V".pattern."\v\\>")
```

the following works perfect:

```
let index = match(line, "\\<".pattern."\\>")
```

Does anyone have an idea how to combine those two things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with `\V`, the backslash still has a special meaning, so `\<...\>` should continue to work. I personally would put the `\V` at the front, and use single quotes to avoid doubling the backslashes:

```
let index = match(line, '\V\<'.pattern.'\>')
```

I guess you intent to match any literal text in `pattern` as whole words. For that to work, you still need to escape backslashes. This is how it's usually done:

```
let index = match(line, '\V\<'.escape(pattern, '\').'\>')
```

The reason that this may fail to match is when `pattern` does not start / end with a keyword character. If you need to handle that, you'd have to check `pattern` first and only conditionally add the `\<` and `\>`. (The check can by done by matching with `\k`.)

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you. I actually tried this before, but I had another issue, that the pattern was not trimmed and there was a space at the end!